# WCF get List<CustomClass> row by row (streaming)

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, streaming

I have WCF service which return many rows from Mysql database.
If get all rows at once I have some delay which not comfortable for me.
I can open mysql datareader and get first rows very quickly but how return this rows to WCF client and continue get rows?

Is it possible make something like streaming but not for binary file stream but for some like List?

Main goal - at client side some thread call WCF stream method which returning row by row and  proceed it.

P.S. Solution which call method with paging (offset in resultset and limit of rows) not so good because call mysql query each time for get portion of data very expensive.

Thanks for help.

Comment: maybe this could help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

Comment: As I see in this article described about streaming large binary information like File. I'm already using file stream transfer but don't know how make transfer List of custom objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look at WCF callbacks. Here is a good startign point:

[What You Need To Know About One-Way Calls, Callbacks, And Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx)

You can make a callback to the client for each row you loaded from the database.